# Interact with web page using javascript injection in a Safari Extension

Tags: javascript, html, safari-extension

I'm very new to developing Safari Extensions and I don't know any java, css or html.

I've been searching round the web for a way to interact with a website using javascript injection. Specifically, I wish to fill out two forms; a username and a password and then press the 'login' button.

I've learned that I need to use something like `document.getElementById()` and `.click` and `.value`, but I really don't know how to connect the dots.

Any help is much appreciated!

Kind regards, Tokke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that when you say *two forms, username and password* you mean two text inputs, and then submit the form.

What you should do, is:

1. Select each text input and change its `value` attribute.
2. Submit the form

Could be done with the following code, assuming that your form has an `id="my-form"`, your username input has `id="username"` and your password input has `id="password"`.

```
document.getElementById("username").value = "myusername"; // Select and fill username input
document.getElementById("password").value = "mypassword"; // Select and fill password input
document.getElementById("my-form").submit();              // Submit the form
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! That's exactly what I mean. The web page is [link](https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/143/login.aspx?lecafdeling=4733693215) and I believe the ids are "m_Content_username2", "m_Content_password2" and "m_Content_submitbtn2" respectively. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. I pasted what you wrote, replaced the ids and saved the file as a .js file using Text Wrangler. I then added the .js file as an End Script, but I can't get the script to run from the extension. Am I doing it right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer solves your problem, don't forget to mark it as valid answer by clicking on the tick next to it ;)

Comment: @Tokke make sure that the third line you use `aspnetForm` instead of `m_Content_submitbtn2`. Otherwise you are trying to 'submit the button' instead of the actual form.

Comment: @Tokke if you will post the content of your extension's Info.plist file and the injected script, someone can perhaps see what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I really appreciate it. I found out that I forgot to click "Include Secure Pages" and therefor, obviously, nothing happened. I did however encounter another problem. The .submit() function was causing a loop on the login page. I tried switching it to a .click() function on the submit button instead of submitting the form, and it worked. :)